# How does being addicted affect you?

Tags: fallout-4

I was carrying too much and decide to drink some whiskey for additional strength. I did that a few times and then I got a notification say "You are now addicted to alcohol". How will the affect the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Withdrawal symptoms are shown on the effects page on your Pip Boy.

[image: effects screen]

This is available on the STAT > STATUS page by pressing the SHOW EFFECTS button:

[image: pipboy menu bar]

Comment: I am minorly disgusted that you have not used those 7 skill points sir and or madam.....

Comment: yes but I don't know when I'm going to need new things! I'm not even that far in the story due to doing lots of side missions. Who knows when I might need hacking to get through a door and have to spend lots of points! :)

Comment: +1 to saving perk points. I try to keep one or two spares on-hand at all times in case I need to boost hacking/lockpicking or something else that I otherwise couldn't have predicted well enough to appropriately prioritize.