# Do item effects stack in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I made a few squirrel stews in Fallout 4 which have the effect that I receive an extra 2% of experience for 2 hours. So when I eat 4 of them do I get 8% for the next 2 hours, 2% for the next 8 hours or still the base value?

Comment: Why not try it and check the [effects screen in pip boy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243149/52800)?

Comment: If it works similar to health, I would assume 2% for 8 hours, but I would be interested in what actually happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

In your case, consuming multiple squirrel stews will only increase your experience gain by 2%.

In order for effects to stack, you need to consume items of different kinds. For instance, if you consume 2 different kinds of alcohol, the second one will override the effects of the first one. However, if you consume a strength enhancing alcohol like Whiskey, and a strength enhancing chem like Buffout, the effects *will* stack. In that case, you would gain +4 strength instead of only +2.

In other words: you'll need to consume something else along with your squirrel stew, if you want to increase your experience gain by more than 2%.

Comment: **Order matters** and it's **not true** that the higher stat is kept. If you take beer then whiskey, you get +1 CHR, +2 STR, -1 INT. If you take whiskey then beer, you only get +1 CHR, +1 STR, -1 INT.